# callback funciton as a string with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this plugin on one of my pages: http://addthisevent.com/  I'd like to add tracking to it, so that I know who added which events via AJAX call.  They have a callback function, but under their Install and FAQ it shows that it has to be a string like so:

```
`callback: ['calTrack()']`
```

but I want to access the id or class of the clicked element so I can pass that to the server for tracking.

Doing something this simple works

```
function calTrack(){
    alert("hello");
}
```

But when I try to do something like this:

```
function calTrack(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

I get undefined.  I also tied doing it like this:
    `callback: ['calTrack(this)']`

```
function calTrack(e){
    alert($(e).attr('id'));
}
```

Also get undefined.  Can someone please help me understand how this works?  How do I either pass a parameter to a string callback function or be able to get to THIS after a function is called?  What am I missing?  Thank you.

Comment: what does `console.log(arguments)` give you? and `console.log(this)`?

Comment: Is the missing single quote a typo or are you running your script without it?

Comment: You are definitely using this incorrectly.

Comment: thanks for showing addthisevent site =)

Comment: @Kevin B, console.log(arguments) also gives undefined.  If I try console.log(this) It just says Window.  Can't figure out how to pass what was clicked to the function from the callback declaration

Comment: then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: @James, what's the correct way to use this?

Comment: @RUJordan, yes sorry, totally missed the closing quote when I typed it in here, I had it correct in the actual code.  So that's not the problem.  I just can't figure out exactly how callback as a string works.  It's so much easier the way callback functions work with jQuery, I understand those

Comment: Try asking in the comments section at the bottom of the plugin's website, it seems to be getting responded to.

Comment: @Kevin B, thanks, that was the first thing I did 2 hours ago ;) before posting here.  Still no response there.  But i think this is more of a generic JS question?

Answer (score 0):

```
function calTrack(){
    alert($(this).attr('id));
}
```

what is $(this) in your function?

try

```
function calTrack(elem){
    alert($(elem).attr('id'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that also comes back as undefined.  How do I pass the elem to the function from where it's being called?

Comment: Because I have dozens of the buttons on the page, it's an event calendar.  And I want to track which event was clicked by which member so I can change the icon on the button after it was clicked to indicate that this event was loaded and so we can have a record of it in DB.

Comment: @Anatoliy, do you have any other suggestions for how to make it work?  Thanks -Roman